# Not able to impersonate user on custom page, where tridion is enabled with adfs saml authentication

Tags: sites-9.1, custom-page, tridion-sites

I am trying to Impersonate user based on current session user but getting nothing on

```
string identityName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

identityName variable is empty.

currently we are using Tridion Sites 9.1, and it is enabled with adfs SAML 2.0.

custom page webapplication is added under Tridion Sites -> Custom Page

Could someone please help/suggest me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19566/tridion-web-sites-cloud-sso-and-custom-pages

Comment: Thanks @RickPannekoek, was able to get current user from given article. :)

Comment: after getting current user I am getting access denied while trying to create core-service session, is it because SAML configuration?
looked into this article as per this I believe core-service does not support SAML https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21218/saml-enabled-system-content-porter-not-working

Comment: Well, "it's complicated" :-)  Core Service does support SAML to some extent (it has so-called Federation bindings which let you pass an entire Claim Set in the form of a SAML token).  But if impersonating by user name is sufficient, you can do that (using the user named obtained like above).

Comment: I think in this scenario there is no connection between the current user (i.e. a Windows user accessing your custom page) and the AD user which has access to Tridion. I don't see how HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name would get you anywhere. To impersonate the user you probably need to look for a claim in the request somewhere - IF that is being set in the first place.